# Vagrant to run play framework

Tags: java, playframework, vagrant

I am using vagrant to run my playframework based java project in ubuntu enviornment

I have set my play setup directory path to PATH enviornment varible, But when I am running play command it is showing me error

```
vagrant@precise64:/$ play
play: SoX v14.3.2

play FAIL sox: Not enough input filenames specified

Usage summary: [gopts] [[fopts] infile]... [fopts] [effect [effopt]]...
```

But when I am running ./play command in my setup directory it working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you have installed one package named `sox` that brings a `play` command.

So when you run `play something` you are executing that program and not the play framework one.

So you should:

- Remove that package: it is not installed by default in Ubuntu so unless you really need it for other purposes you should remove it

  ```
  apt-get remove sox
  ```
- Add play framework to your PATH. Supposing your play installation is in `/opt/play`, just do something like

  ```
  export PATH=/opt/play/bin:$PATH
  ```

You should add those commands in the required file (ex: bootstrap.sh).

Comment: thanks to reply. But when I am removing getting following error
vagrant@precise64:/$ apt-get remove sox
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: uninstallation done actually I was not using sudo with command